# Can I restore Test Cases/Test Suite I accidentally deleted from Azure DevOps

Tags: testing, azure-devops, restore, testcase, manual-testing

We are using Scrum and in last Sprint (Sprint2) I manually run some test cases with success. We just started new Sprint3 and I first created new test suite for Sprint3. Then I noticed there is also possibility to copy test plan and I tried to copy Test Suite 2 for Test Suite 3. After that I somehow had two test suites for Sprint3 and I deleted another of those.
Then I tried to check what was tested in Sprint2 but now those successfull test cases are not in Test Suite 2 anymore. Do you know if there is a way to return to previous state or somehow restore the tests that I already run.
Our testing is manual and Test Cases are linked to Product Backlog Items.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions how to improve your question. Mainly post code snippets of your work so other can see what may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, according to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/delete-test-artifacts?view=azure-devops):

> We only support permanent deletion of test artifacts such as test
>   plans, test suites, test cases, shared steps and shared parameters.
>   Deleted test artifacts won't appear in the recycle bin and cannot be
>   restored.

Thus the deleted test artifacts will be permanently deleted.